# ClassNotFoundException with EHCache-Atomikos

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache, jta, atomikos

I'm trying to use EHCache's transactional abilities together with Atomikos and Apache Tomcat (for usage with JMS and Hibernate but that's just to assure the sceptics I really need JTA).

I'm currently working on a small POC where I'm trying to put an instance of `MyValue` which implements `Serializable` and when I try to commit the transaction I get the __ with `ClassNotFoundException` as the root (The stack trace is at the end).

When I jar the `MyValue` file and put it under %TOMCAT_HOME%\lib I get no exception.

It's important to add that due to an instruction I saw on the [atomikos tutorial](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/Tomcat6Integration35#Important_note) both Atomikos's jars and EHCache jars are under %TOMCAT_HOME%\lib.

**This is the quote:**

> When the Atomikos transaction manager is installed globally in Tomcat, you now must also install your JDBC driver at the same global location (ie: into the TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder). If you don't do that, you will get a NoClassDefFoundErrors or a ClassNotFoundException or even a ClassCastException during your web application deployment.
>   This is not a limitation of Atomikos nor of Tomcat but of the J2EE class loading design that both Tomcat and Atomikos must follow.

The problem is that I cannot have all my value classes under that folder, of course.

Have I misenterperted the instruction?

Has anyone encountered this issue?

***EHCache.xml***

```
<cache name="myCache"  
       maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
       eternal="true"  
       overflowToDisk="false"  
       diskPersistent="false"  
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"  
        transactionalMode="xa"  
 />
```

***Stack trace***

```
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: When configured copyOnRead or copyOnWrite, a Store will only accept Serializable values  
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.SerializationCopyStrategy.copy(SerializationCopyStrategy.java:47)  
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.Segment.potentiallyCopy(Segment.java:176)  
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.Segment.create(Segment.java:342)  
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.Segment.put(Segment.java:400)  
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore.put(CompoundStore.java:132)  
at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.StorePutCommand.execute(StorePutCommand.java:43)  
at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.VersionAwareWrapper.execute (VersionAwareWrapper.java:68)  
at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.EhcacheXAResourceImpl.prepareInternal(EhcacheXAResourceImpl.java:224)  
at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.TransactionXARequestProcessor$XARequestCallable.call(TransactionXARequestProcessor.java:150)  
at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.TransactionXARequestProcessor$XARequestCallable.call(TransactionXARequestProcessor.java:117)  
at net.sf.ehcache.transaction.xa.XAThreadPool$MultiRunner.run(XAThreadPool.java:115)  
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myCompany.testJTA.MyValue  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)  
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)  
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:604)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:480)  
at net.sf.ehcache.Element.readObject(Element.java:796)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)  
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.SerializationCopyStrategy.copy (SerializationCopyStrategy.java:45)  
... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's important to add that due to an instruction I saw on the atomikos tutorial both Atomikos's jars and EHCache jars are under %TOMCAT_HOME%\lib

Classes from a web application (i.e. loaded by a ***WebappX*** classloader) aren't visible from the ***Common*** classloader (see the [Apache Tomcat 6.0 - Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) ), which is why you get a CNFE.

Now, the question is, why do you put the EHCache JAR in the ***Common*** classloader? I don't think you need to. Package it at your web application level.

#### References

- [Apache Tomcat 6.0 - Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

Comment: Hi Pascal, What you cited is what I suspected (hence my successfully workaround). The motivation for the location of the EHCache jars is lited above with a link with regard to the atomikos tutorial

Comment: @Ittai: Well, if you want to use Tomcat's connection pool, you need to put the JDBC driver (and also the jar providing AtomikosDataSourceBean i.e. Atomikos) in the Common classloader (for the reasons mentioned above). But the case of EHCache is different, neither Tomcat nor Atomikos are instantiating EHCache stuff. Just put it at the app level.

Comment: thanks a lot. I suspected I mistakenly generalized the comment but since I'm not too familiar with App servers I wasn't sure.